# What can a non-Mac App Store app do in terms of sandboxing and security?

Tags: macos, mac, security, permissions, sandbox

I'm curious about what applications from outside of the Mac App Store limitations are. By default, what are their permissions? What can they access on my computer?

From my perspective, I can see that the "Open" dialog is executed by the OS frameworks to give only access to certain file/folder. Is it how this work?